# how to record and play sound in real time simultaneously?

Tags: audio-streaming, wav, pcm, waveout

I have a reciever, I want to be able to hear the audio the receiver is transmitting and to save this audio as a wav file.
I have written a client-server app to communicate with the receiver.
The receiver is transmitting the audio throuh udp, I play the audio using the WaveOut functions, but i have encoutered some problems:

1) Is there any way to use the WaveIn functions in order record the audio?
i tried somthing in this way but get dev caps func didn't find any device.
can i fool the func to think there is a device?

2) I tried to write the data directly as a wav file and noticed there is a noise that is beeing added to the stream. did i need to write first the data as a raw pcm and then convert it to wav file, or there is another way?

any other suggestions?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are WaveIn and WaveOut? What programming language/library/OS are you using? What kind of device are you streaming from? Which protocol does it use? Etc.

Comment: WaveOut and WaveIn are from the win32api for example(waveOutPrepareHeader
waveOutWrite
waveOutUnprepareHeader).i work in win 7 vs2010 c++. i stream from an icom receiver. need any more info?

Comment: I don't know win32api, so I can't help you with that. At the very least, not without seeing any code examples. Additionally, what kind of noise do you hear in the WAV file? Static? Pops/ticks? Crackling? These all indicate different kinds of problems.

Comment: WAV, as it is most commonly used, is essentially a wrapper around raw PCM data, so it shouldn't be needed to write PCM first and then convert it to WAV.

Comment: So how can I continue to write to a wav file. like: "RIFF ,fmt, data, data, data,...." ? Did I need to start a new thread just for write to the file or can I do them both in the same function?

Comment: You haven't posted any code examples, so how am I supposed to know whether that's needed? Besides, I don't know the Windows API (at all).